# This PHP code get the same AT command in device respond

Tags: php

Am trying to send AT commands to my GSMmodem device ,  in linux with PHP
Am sure it is /dev/ttyusb1
But with [this code](http://pastebin.com/aut4ygXf) device respond the same command and code prints that command
e.g if we send ATD00 it responds ATD00 , or with AT it responds AT instead of Ok, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Weird but solved with using another symbolink of Device
Weird because other App in linux in the same time were using for example /dev/ttyusb1 but php code works with /dev/ttyusb3